# WinError 3 в библиотеке WatchDog

Tags: python, модули

При запуске этого кода

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import os
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

folder_track = '/Users/Anton/Downloads'
folder_dest = '/users/Anton/Desktop/Music'

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_track):
            extension = filename.split(".")
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == "mp3"):
                file = folder_track + "/" + filename
                new_path = folder_dest + "/" + filename
                os.replace(folder_track + "/" + filename, new_path + "/" + filename)



handle = Handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(handle, folder_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Выдаёт такой traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "G:/PyCharmProjects/main.py", line 23, in 
> observer.start()   File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py",
> line 260, in start
> emitter.start()   File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\utils_*init*_.py",
> line 110, in start
> self.on_thread_start()   File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\read_directory_changes.py",
> line 66, in on_thread_start
> self._handle = get_directory_handle(self.watch.path)   File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py",
> line 307, in get_directory_handle
> return CreateFileW(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, WATCHDOG_FILE_SHARE_FLAGS,   File
> "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py",
> line 113, in _errcheck_handle
> raise ctypes.WinError() FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь.

Comment: Ну собственно проблема решилась сама собой. Как? не понятно.